# Knockout dependances and how to use a nullable observable as link to another viewmodel observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding

Let's say you have a list of Client[] that is loaded in async, while you have your Item[] already accessible.
For one item specifically, how do you do bindings that depends on an originally undefined observable (or any other thing that would work in knockoutjs)?

**JsFiddle link**

**http://jsfiddle.net/darknessm0404/5exLf/4/**

---

```
<div id="item1">
     Client name: <span data-bind="text:client().name"></span>
     ...
</div>
```

The goal would be to have knockout display the good values without having to manually managing subscriptions.

Is that possible and how could it be done?

jsFiddle contains:

```
var Item = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.onClick = function() {
        self.client(client1);
    };
    this.client = ko.observable(); // undefined => not linked to another property yet
};

var client1 = {
                name:'Test name',
                changeableBackground: ko.observable('#00FF00')
              };

ko.applyBindings(new Item());
```

---

If I supply *this.client* with *client1* and if I put *text:client().name* it works I know, but it's not what I'm trying to achieve, since I do not have the *client1* information, it will fail on client().name at initialization.

Comment: You can check that `client` has some value in your binding with : `<span data-bind="text: client() && client().name"></span>` http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/56EcL/

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll use that if there's no other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statement `text: client.name` is invalid and senseless, because `client` is not an object, `client` is a function.
You should extract object (with `()` operator), and then get property *name*, so you should always use `client().name`

To resolve you problem I can propose next solutions:

**1)** Initialize `client` with empty object

```
self.client = ko.observable({});
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CC4Bn/)

**2)** Add additional validation, like

```
data-bind="text: client() ? client().name : ''"
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Bbck/)

**3)** Use utility function

```
get : function(obj, prop)
{
    return obj ? obj[prop] : null;
}
//...  
data-bind="text: Utils.get(client(), 'name')"
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qjSw4/)

Comment: Empty object (1) wouldn't work in cases where there are several levels (object) inside client (client.name was a typo, I fixed it in the examples).